# Compiling program with ncurses in c++ returns error

Tags: c++, linux, clang++

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/clang++ -v -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g /home/lev/Desktop/Code/Loading/main.cpp -o /home/lev/Desktop/Code/Loading/main
clang version 14.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/bin/clang-14" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debug-info-kind=constructor -dwarf-version=5 -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Loading -resource-dir /usr/lib/clang/14.0.6 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/clang/14.0.6/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Loading -ferror-limit 19 -stack-protector 2 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /tmp/main-4bf7f3.o -x c++ /home/lev/Desktop/Code/Loading/main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 14.0.6 based upon LLVM 14.0.6 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0
 /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/backward
 /usr/lib/clang/14.0.6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -pie --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o /home/lev/Desktop/Code/Loading/main /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../lib64/Scrt1.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0 -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/main-4bf7f3.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/crtendS.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../lib64/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
/build/glibc/src/glibc/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:103: undefined reference to `main'
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

is the error in question, the code is `#include <ncurses.h>`

, if I do anything more in the library it will tell me it's an undefined reference

I am on Arch Linux

I need this resolved because I want to learn ncurses and don't want to use python because of how indentation is used instead of {} and how it's not meant to be compiled into an exactable file

With the new code

```cpp
#include <ncurses.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    initscr();
    refresh();
    endwin();


    return 0;
}
```

I get the error

```
 *  Executing task: C/C++: clang++ build active file 

Starting build...
/usr/bin/clang++ -fcolor-diagnostics -v -fansi-escape-codes -g "/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp/main.cpp" -o "/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp/main"
clang version 14.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/bin/clang-14" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debug-info-kind=constructor -dwarf-version=5 -debugger-tuning=gdb -v "-fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp" -resource-dir /usr/lib/clang/14.0.6 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/clang/14.0.6/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro "-fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp" -ferror-limit 19 -stack-protector 2 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /tmp/main-f26304.o -x c++ "/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp/main.cpp"
clang -cc1 version 14.0.6 based upon LLVM 14.0.6 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0
 /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/backward
 /usr/lib/clang/14.0.6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp/main.cpp:2:17: warning: using directive refers to implicitly-defined namespace 'std'
using namespace std;
                ^
1 warning generated.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -pie --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o "/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp/main" /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../lib64/Scrt1.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0 -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/main-f26304.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/crtendS.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/main-f26304.o: in function `main':
/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `initscr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `refresh'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `endwin'
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

After adding -lncurses to the compilation command the error is

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -fcolor-diagnostics -v -lncurses -fansi-escape-codes -g "/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp/main.cpp" -o "/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp/main"
clang version 14.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/bin/clang-14" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debug-info-kind=constructor -dwarf-version=5 -debugger-tuning=gdb -v "-fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp" -resource-dir /usr/lib/clang/14.0.6 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/clang/14.0.6/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro "-fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp" -ferror-limit 19 -stack-protector 2 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /tmp/main-687730.o -x c++ "/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp/main.cpp"
clang -cc1 version 14.0.6 based upon LLVM 14.0.6 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0
 /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/backward
 /usr/lib/clang/14.0.6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp/main.cpp:2:17: warning: using directive refers to implicitly-defined namespace 'std'
using namespace std;
                ^
1 warning generated.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -pie --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o "/home/lev/Desktop/Code/Ncurses Cpp/main" /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../lib64/Scrt1.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0 -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/lib -L/usr/lib -lncurses /tmp/main-687730.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/crtendS.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../lib64/crtn.o

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Comment: Well... do you have a `main` function in your program?

Comment: `undefined reference to 'main'` - So... where is *your* `main` function, and is it being linked with your program??

Comment: *and don't want to use python because of how indentation is used instead of {}* -- That isn't a good reason why you shouldn't use python.  Every language has their syntax rules.

Comment: Don't confuse "learning" with "being comfortable with the way things operate". The point of learning is to be *uncomfortable*. Maybe you don't like Python, but it might be educational to at least *try*.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  I have tried, I just like c++ more, also I don't like typing Libraryname.function() instead of function()

Comment: You don't seem to have li ked with NCurses. Add `-lncurses` to the end of your compile command.

Comment: @Dúthomhas It doesn't work (but does change the message), I edited now

Comment: Sorry, it looks like it is also trying to decide between 32 and 64 bit, which is a co figuration issue. Have you tried being explicit with `-m64` or `-m33`?

Comment: @Dúthomhas It changed the error once more, it exits with code -1 and says that miDebuggerPath is invalid and when I click the launch.json button it creates a launch.json which for some reason did not exist before.

Comment: I really can’t just keep guessing. I am unfamiliar with VSCode (I presume that is what you are using?). Can you not just compile at the shell prompt with `clang++ -O3 -std=c++17 main.cpp -lncurses`? If that does not work then you have a system configuration error. Otherwise you have a VSCode (or whatever IDE you are using) configuration error.

Comment: Why are you doing `using namespace std;`? You haven't included a single header file that declares anything in `std`.

Comment: Thanks @Dúthomhas , the command you gave me worked and I might as well use that since vscode's term is not full screen meaning it would throw a lot of errors with ncurses (or at least not work).

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference as long as the terminal emulator is properly configured. Just read the screen size and set the NCurses window resize event hook if it matters. It might be worth spending some time looking through VSCode's configuration options. Sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to run `ncurses6-config  --cflags` and use those flags for compilation